# C++ TBB concurrent_bounded_queue - pop timeout

Tags: c++, concurrency, tbb

I noticed that TBB concurrent_bounded_queue blocking pop has no timeout. We are moving to TBB from another implementation where we had timed wait and hence looking for the same functionalities here.

In any case, it's often useful to have timed-wait, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[According to Arch Robinson](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/301099), the architect of TBB, timeouts were never a priority:

> The initial design of TBB targeted a paradigm of task-based programming for parallel speedup. It is what I think of as "classical" parallel algorithms like parallel_for, parallel_reduce, etc.The containers and mutexes were designed with that in mind; i.e., to avoid race conditions.Blocking was expected to be short, otherwise the program would not scale. Therefore timeouts were not a priority.

There's an [old article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/09/17/pondering-timed-mutex) where one of the TBB engineers discusses timed mutexes. You probably won't be able to use the workaround sketched there directly, but it can help you implement a blocking dequeue yourself, basing it off on `concurrent_queue`'s not blocking `try_pop`.

I wouldn't expect the performance to be anywhere near that of just using the TBB queues, and it won't be that trivial (probably 100+ LOC), but if you really want it, it can be done.

P.S. Java `BlockingQueue`-style blocking poll/offer with a timeout is something that you probably don't want to be using on your fast paths. A couple of times I have started an implementation with such a method, only to find after some period of time (no pun intended), that either producer/consumer pressure is not enough and just blocking is at least as efficient, or I need to investigate what happens and rethink some part of my code.